# How to set multiple variable input by name while starting a linux script

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu

I'm using Linux Ubuntu server.

There, I want to run a script called **hello.sh**.

And I want to pass multiple parameter by name, while executing the script.

Something like,

```
./hello.sh -name=abc -age=33
```

and
the script would be like

```
echo My name is $name and I'm $age yrs old.
```

........................................................

So, my question is, is it possible? if yes, then how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you have in question but you can use something like this:

```
fn() {
   declare "$@";
   echo "My name is $name and I'm $age yrs old.";
}

fn name=abc age=33
```

**Output:**

```
My name is abc and I'm 33 yrs old.
```

**PS:** You have to make sure to use legal variable names in command line.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                          

set -eu         # Exit on errors and unbound variables.
args=(name age)

_IFS=$IFS
IFS='|'
pattern="${args[*]}"
IFS=$_IFS

error () {
    echo "$1" >&2
    exit $2
}

while (( $# )) ; do
    if [[ $1 == -*=* ]] ; then
        var=${1%%=*}                         # Everything up to the first =.
        if [[ $var != -@($pattern) ]] ; then # Only the listed arguments allowed.
            error "Unknown parameter $var" 2
        fi

        val=${1#*=}
        declare ${var#-}=$val                # It's now safe to create the variable.
        shift
    else
        error "Invalid parameter format: $1" 1
    fi
done

echo "My name is $name and I'm $age years old."
```